# compiler order with gcc 4.8.5

Tags: gcc

My gcc version is 4.8.5

- posix gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)

I have two cpp files：

- 1.cpp and 2.cpp

while there is a static function in 1.cpp called by 2.cpp。
In most machine，we should like this：

- g++ 2.cpp 1.cpp

or it will cause compile error or runtime error。

However，in my machine with gcc 4.8.5，I must compile using “g++ 1.cpp 2.cpp” to make it run successful。

Is this the property of gcc4.8.5？ or there is something wrong on my soft，or I used it wrong？

==============================================================

My machine is centos7 installed on virtulbox of mac. Here is my code:

---

1.h

```
 #include <map>   
 using namespace std;

 class A {
    private:
        A();
        static A _instance;
        map<int, int> test_map;
    public:
        static A& get_instance();
        static void fun();
    };
```

1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "1.h"

using namespace std;

A A::_instance;

A::A() {
    cout << "A::A()\n";
}

A& A::get_instance() {
    cout << "A::get_instance()\n";
    return A::_instance;
    // static A instance;
    // return instance;
}

void A::fun() {
    cout << "A::fun()\n";
    get_instance().test_map[1];
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "1.h"
using namespace std;

int test() {
    cout << "test()\n";
    A::fun();
    return 0;
}
int y = test();

int main() {
    cout << "main()\n";
    A::fun();
}
```

---

In most machine and in what I see in the web, we should compile like this:
    g++ main.cpp 1.cpp

But in my machine, I must compile like this:
    g++ 1.cpp main.cpp

what's wrong with my machine or my gcc?

Comment: Can you provide example code and error messages to clarify the question? E.g. `static function in 1.cpp called by 2.cpp` does not make sense (static function can not be called outside of file it's defined in).

Comment: thanks for your opinion, I edited the question and added my code. Looking forwarding to you solutions.

Comment: Please also provide details of what is the error you see. Order of files should not matter at all unless you rely on undefined behavior (like order of static constructors).

Comment: both way in all machines will compile successful. In other machine, executable file generated by "g++ main.cpp 1.cpp" run successful while file by "g++ 1.cpp main.cpp" will cause segment fault; In my machine, the behiver of rumtime got the opposite result.

Comment: Like what you said, I think the undefined behavior of the order of static constructors cause this difference. And I think I should write the code of singleton in another way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) which is a classical C++ bug. If initialization function `test()` in main.cpp is called before constructor for `A::_instance` has been called, your code will access uninitialized `A::_instance::test_map` field which is likely to cause segmentation fault. I suggest you rewrite `getInstance` to create instance when needed:

```
A *A::_instance;

A& A::get_instance() {
  cout << "A::get_instance()\n";
  if(!_instance)
    _instance = new A;
  return *A::_instance;
}
```

As a side note, I suggest you to use [AddressSanitizer](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerInitializationOrderFiasco) to autodetect this and similar types of errors.